# I would like to hide/unhide next row below in my Excel using VBA Macro with a button and use same macro for different rows and different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to hide/unhide next row below in my Excel using VBA Macro with a button and use same macro for different rows and different sheets.

I will copy paste this button in several rows and whenever i click it it should toggle hide/unhide the next row only.
Can you please guide me with proper Macro script to do this.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service, but if you post something you've tried we'll be happy to help you edit it